# Red [ERROR] output in python in ROS

Tags: ros, python

In ROS, I cannot get [ERROR] logs to print in red when I use python. How can I make them appear in red instead of black?

For example, the following Python:

```
rospy.logerr("No analog input received.")
```

produces this output in **black**:

> [ERROR] [WallTime: 135601422.876123] No analog input received.

whereas the following C++:

```
ROS_ERROR("No analog input received.");
```

produces the following output in **red**.

> [ERROR] [135601551.192412]: No analog input received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been merged as of six weeks ago:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/8a1f92fc0c888099fe47005f609883601b7d8d72#diff-1

Answer (score 7):

Please see this bug ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3691

I filed this bug report (with patch to fix) 13 months ago and am pretty disappointed in the ROS team that they have not put this in trunk.

Comment: It seems that a lot of ROS development is moving towards Github's issues and pull requests, because the Trac site has become abysmal.  Not to create more work for you, but if you file an issue and pull request on http://github.com/ros/ros_comm, it will be more likely to be handled.